# Product of the off-diagonal block matrices

Tags: block-matrices

Consider two real symmetric positive matrices $A\geq0$ and $B\geq 0$ with the following block form
\begin{equation}
A=
  \begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
    A_{11} & A_{12} \\ \hline
    A_{21} & A_{22}  \\
  \end{array}\end{pmatrix}, \quad B=\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
    B_{11} & B_{12} \\ \hline
    B_{21} & B_{22}  \\
  \end{array}\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
I need to know if $A_{12}B_{21}\geq 0$.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What do you mean by "positive" ? All entries positive or "symmetric **definite** positive" ?

Comment: Please answer our questions.

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry for the confusion. Is matrix $A_{12} B_{21}\geq 0$ in the sense of nonnegative eigenvalues?

Comment: Having all eigenvalues $\ge 0$ is synonymous of **a semi-definite positive matrix** ; if it is $>0$ : it means "positive definite matrix".

Comment: @JeanMarie noted, thanks.

Comment: The answer is no. Counter-example with the symmetric positive definite matrices :
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}9&-3&-2&-1\\
-3&7&-1&1\\
-2&-1&7&-3\\
-1&1&-3&3
\end{pmatrix} \ \text{and} \ B=\begin{pmatrix}4&1&-1&1\\
1&2&0&-2\\
-1&0&4&0\\
1&-2&0&4
\end{pmatrix}$$. I let you compute $A_{12}B_{21}$. You will see that its eigenvalues are $-3,2$. In other cases one finds that $A_{12}B_{21}$ is non-symmetrical...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks